# Prove that if (X, $\mathcal{A}$, $\mu$) is a measure space, $f$ is measureable $/iff$ $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if (X, $\mathcal{A}$, $\mu$) is a measure space, $f$ is measureable $\iff$ $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable$\mathcal{A}$

Where

$f^-(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } f(x) > 0 \\
  -f(x) & \mbox{if } f(x) \leq 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

$f^+(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f(x)  & \mbox{if } f(x) \geq 0 \\
  0& \mbox{if } f(x) < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

So far I have shown that

$f^+(x) - f^-(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f(x)  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  f(x) & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

so $f^+(x) - f^-(x)= f(x)$

but I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned that the sum of two measurable functions is measurable? What about the max of two measurable functions?

Comment: No, so I don't think that will be a suitable solution.

Comment: What definition of measurable function have you been given?

Comment: let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(Y,T)$ be a topological space. 

Let $ f: X \rightarrow Y$ we say that $f$ is measureable if the inverse image of each open set is $\mu$-measureable. 

i.e. $f^{-1}(u) \in \mathcal{A}, \forall u \in T$

Comment: No additional characterization when $Y$ is $\mathbb R$?

Comment: No, just that so far. But do you have a suggestion for a possible solution, when Y is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Measurable_Functions could this possibly help?

Comment: no, that is the usual way and you use the fact that sum and maximum of measurable functions is measurable. I'm typing an answer that does not use those results right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable, and let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb R$. Denote by $U^+=U\cap[0,+\infty)$ and $U^-=U\cap(-\infty,0)$. Then,
$$
f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}\left(U^+\cup U^-\right)=\underbrace{f^{-1}(U^+)}_{=(f^+)^{-1}(U^+)\in\mathcal A}\cup\underbrace{f^{-1}(U^-)}_{=(f^-)^{-1}(-U^-)\in\mathcal A}\in\mathcal A.
$$
Conversely, assume that $f$ is measurable. Let us show for example that $f^+$ is measurable (you proceed similarly for $f^-$). Let $U$ be an open set. If $0\notin U$, then
$$
(f^+)^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U\cap(0,+\infty))\in\mathcal{A}.
$$
If $0\in U$, then 
$$
(f^+)^{-1}(U)=(f^+)^{-1}(\{0\})\cup f^{-1}(U\cap(0,+\infty))=\underbrace{f^{-1}((-\infty,0))}_{\in\mathcal A}\cup\underbrace{f^{-1}(U\cap(0,+\infty))}_{\in\mathcal A}\in\mathcal A.
$$

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much.

Comment: @Ian Is your proof with open sets is only valid, if $\mathcal A$ is the Borel-Sigma algebra ?

Comment: @derivative, recall that $f$ goes from $(X,\mathcal A)$ to $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$. So I need $\mathcal B$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (since I look at Borel sets of $\mathbb R$). But $\mathcal A$ can be any $\sigma$-algebra, since I do not use its structure in the proof.